# ASP.net session variables information required

Tags: asp.net, session-variables

I have an ASP.net WebForms application. I have used session variables in my application. I have a requirement of getting the memory used by the session variables on the aspx.cs pages. How do i do that. For a start I know that i can get it done like this.

```
int totalSessionBytes;
BinaryFormatter b = new BinaryFormatter();
MemoryStream m;
b.Serialize(m, Session["table1"]);
totalSessionBytes = m.Length;
```

Any other suitable way other than this? Some of my session variables also save DataTables. Will i be able to capture the mem of such session variables?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the total-memory-used by the session store only works if you're using the `InProc` store - if you're using an external store for session-state like Redis or SQL-Server then the answer is zero.

Your proposed approach will at least **double** the apparent memory usage of session-state because you're performing a copy (of serialized data!) to a `MemoryStream` which parents a `Byte[]` and then you never `Dispose` it, leaving it up to the GC gods to decide when to lower your memory pressure. Your approach also only returns data for the current user's session state, rather than that of all users.

The problem is also compounded if you consider things like String Interning (where identical string values in the .NET runtime are shared by multiple string references) - because those string values could be shared by different users' different session-states.

The only way to find out exactly how much memory being used is to use a memory-profiling tool like [JetBrains dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) or [MemProfiler](https://memprofiler.com/) or the CLR/GC analysis tools in WinDBG and Visual Studio's Diagnostics Tools window.